# How to extract log entries from the last hour?

Tags: linux, awk, logs

I am looking for a one-liner command to extract log entries that have occurred within the last hour from a Postfix mail log file.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158692/how-to-get-logs-of-last-hour-in-linux-using-awk-command), I have attempted to manipulate the suggested command but it is pretty longwinded. I am looking to shorten/improve this. The command I am currently working with is:

```
awk -vDate1=`date -d'now-1 hour' +%H:%M:%S` -vDate2=`date -d'now-1 hour' +%d` '{ if ($3 > Date1 && $2 >= Date2) print $0}' /var/log/maillog
```

The log format of the mail log is as follows:

```
Jan 18 05:55:44 smtp-out-01 postfix/smtpd[8748]: connect from server.com[1.2.3.4]
Jan 18 05:55:44 smtp-out-01 postfix/smtpd[8748]: 70CF214B4: client=server.com[1.2.3.4]
Jan 18 05:55:44 smtp-out-01 postfix/cleanup[8751]: 70CF214B4: message-id=<20180118105544.385A6204039F71@server.com>
Jan 18 05:55:44 smtp-out-01 postfix/qmgr[28134]: 70CF214B4: from=<root@server.com>, size=1806, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

What is the shortest and most efficient way of extracting just the entries from the past hour?

Comment: what if log would contain `Jan 17 ...` ? Then, you should also check other date parts

Comment: Mind day boundaries, month boundaries, year boundaries... perhaps use %s

Comment: If you are running systemd, you can use journalctl -u postfix -S "$(date -d "-1 hour" +%Y"-"%m"-"%d" "%T)"

Comment: @RamanSailopal This seems to be the cleanest and most efficient suggestion - you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
journalctl -u postfix -S "$(date -d "-1 hour" +%Y"-"%m"-"%d" "%T)
```

Use -u to specify the service name and then use -S to specify a "since" date that is generated from the date command

Comment: Or, you could just do "journalctl -u postfix --since=-1h"

Answer (score 1):

`awk -v ldate="$( date +'%d %H-%M-%S' -d'1 hour ago' )" '$2 " " $3 >= ldate'` does what you want I think, but as RomanPerekhrest says, it wont work for the first hour of the month.

anyway, this sets a variable `date` to the day, then time, and then compares the range of fields 2 - 3 for whether they're higher / later than it. They can be concatenated just by adding the required spacing, so only a single date string is needed.

it may be worth changing the dates to a better format, and setting your logger to record a more convenient format, with years too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,
none of the previous sentences worked for me.

(Linux 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu )

My variant ( bash ):

```
k=$(date -d '1 hour ago' +'%H') | egrep "^*$k:" ./my.log
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 i=`date -d "1 hour ago"| awk '{print $2}'`; j=`date -d "1 hour ago"| awk '{print $3}'`;k=`date -d "1 hour ago"| awk '{print $4}'`; awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" -v k="$k" '$1 == i && $2 == j && $3 > k {print $0}'  /var/log/maillog
```

In variable i==> stores Month
In Variable j==> Stores date

In Variable k==> Stores Time duration in format Hour:Minute:Second

My script will check for Current Month,date and check for log which exists between past 1 hour to now.

Let me know for any confusion